# Android - force listview items to use default long click animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, long-click

I have a `ListView` with custom `Adapter` that includes `RadioButton`. My app allows users to long click on every row of `ListView` (via `OnLongClickListener` in `Adapter`, not via `OnItemLongClickListener` on `ListView`), but it isn't animating in the default way. Instead of it, it looks like holding `RadioButton` pressed. Exactly like this:

[image]

But I want to highlight full row during `OnLongClickListener`.

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/languageitem_linear_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/languageitem_text_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_list_name_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/languageitem_text_count"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/adapter_day_calendar_date_text" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/languageitem_progress_downloading"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/languageitem_image_update"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/about_app"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_autorenew_black_36dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/languageitem_image_download"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/about_app"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_36dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/languageitem_radiobutton_selected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried adding empty `OnItemLongClickListener` returning either `true` or `false`, but it didn't change anything. Another idea was to setting `styles.xml`, but I completely have no idea how to.

Can somebody tell me clearly step-by-step explain how to achieve my goal? My min API is 15 (Android 4.1).